# How to do 2-layer nested FOR loop in PYTORCH?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, recommendation-engine, matrix-factorization

I am learning to implement the Factorization Machine in Pytorch.
And there should be some feature crossing operations.
For example, I've got three features [A,B,C], after embedding, they are [vA,vB,vC], so the feature crossing is "[vA·vB], [vA·vC], [vB·vc]".

I know this operation can be simplified by the following:
[image]

It can be implemented by MATRIX OPERATIONS.
But this only gives a final result, say, a single value.

The question is, how to get all cross_vec in the following without doing FOR loop:
note: size of "feature_emb" is [batch_size x feature_len x embedding_size]

```
    g_feature = 0 
    for i in range(self.featurn_len):
        for j in range(self.featurn_len):
            if j <= i: continue
            cross_vec = feature_emb[:,i,:] * feature_emb[:,j,:]       
            g_feature += torch.sum(cross_vec, dim=1)
```

Comment: please do not post screenshots - rather copy-paste the text. SO cannot index text in screen shots.

Comment: what are the dimensions of `A` and `vA` or your `feature_emb` and `cross_vec`?

Comment: A:  batch_size x feature_len
vA: batch_size x feature_len x embedding_size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can

```
cross_vec = (feature_emb[:, None, ...] * feature_emb[..., None, :]).sum(dim=-1)
```

This should give you `corss_vec` of shape `(batch_size, feature_len, feature_len)`.

Alternatively, you can use [`torch.bmm`](https://pytorch.org/docs/0.4.1/torch.html#torch.bmm)

```
cross_vec = torch.bmm(feature_emb, feature_emb.transpose(1, 2))
```

Comment: Your solution gives "dot" results. And I have "if j <= i: continue"  in the for loop. So, my wanted result is of shape (batch_size, (feature_len * (feature_len-1))/2, embedding_size)

Comment: @JinyangLiu the output matrix `corss_vec` is symmetric, you can simply take the upper/lower traingular part of the matrix.

Comment: Great！And use ```cross_vec[:, torch.triu(torch.ones(feature_len, feature_len), diagonal=1) == 1, :]```, I got what I want!!!

Comment: One more question! If I want to get the concatation, that's to say, get ``` (batch_size, (feature_len * (feature_len-1))/2, embedding_size * 2) ``` as the result.